# gnuplot: plot doesn't show completely on larger xrange

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to plot the following function:

```
reset
set terminal svg enhanced \
fname 'Times-Roman' fsize '10'
set output "test.svg"
A = 0.166735265541426
E = 27.3
F = 0.0244
f(x) = (0 < x && x < 2) ? T+((A/(E*sqrt(F*x)))*exp(-0.00003025/(x*F))) : 1/0
```

with

```
set xrange [-0.1:0.5]
```

I want to plot with

```
plot f(x) t 'lit' ls 1 lw 2 lt rgb "green"
```

What I get is the following

[image: fullrange plot]

But I am also interested in the part you can only see with a smaller xrange:

```
set xrange [-0.005:0.01]
```

[image: smallrange]

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to run the plot command again or use `replot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the number of samples:

```
set samples 1000         # or even 10000
```

This is the result with T=58:

[image: image with higher sample rate]

You might want to use something like `set xrange [1e-5:10]; set logscale x`.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for but for some reason didn't find via google et al.